# How to turnoff Debug mode in Jboss server on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, startup, putty, jboss

When I start a JBOSS server 6.4 on my linux machine, it displays all the messages. But I don't want to see those messages, hence need to disable them.

How can I **turn off** those messages in **JBOSS 6.4 server**?

I referred other websites that mentioned making a modification in log4j or jboss_log4j.xml file. But on my machine there are no files like that.